# Use HomePod for Zoom Calls on Mac?

Tags: homepod, zoom.app

I've tried to use a HomePod connected to my Mac to participate in Zoom calls. I wanted to take advantage of the clear audio and the echo suppression one has on the HomePod when, for example, having FaceTime Audio calls. Especially for really long calls, I would prefer external speakers over the AirPods, for example.

However, I have several problems using the HomePod for Zoom calls:

- The **audio I hear is delayed by several seconds**, which is especially noticeable when the speaker is highlighting something on the slides with his pointer, and the video stream is not synced to the audio.
- The **microphone of the HomePod is not used**. Instead, the internal microphone of my Mac or the webcam microphone is used. So, if I am unmuted, other **people speaking** in the call do **hear themselves** through my microphone.

I suppose, the HomePod just isn't made for that kind of use and I should buy a conference mic/speaker. But I wanted to rule out that this might be some kind of configuration issue with my Mac, first. Has anyone used the HomePod successfully for Zoom calls connected to the Mac (not dialling in through a phone line)?